# When I share a link with the editor it shows the system URL and share URL both in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, laravel-8

When I share a link with the editor it shows the system URL and share URL both in Laravel 8.
Please see the attachement.

> 1. I want to share only real links (like [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)) I add a link with my editor when it shows my website it pulls with my current Url /
>    base URL (like
>    'http://127.0.0.1/lara_hypermix/post-details/www.facebook.com'). I
>    want only 'www.facebook.com')
> 2. I want to remove 'http://127.0.0.1/lara_hypermix/post-details/' from my created link.
>    [image]

[image]

Comment: Add some code to see how you are saving that data.

Comment: Please see answer @Tpojka

Comment: Try with full url with prepending scheme. For example "https://www.facebook.com".

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com`

Comment: @Tpojka Many many thanks for your information . Now it works. love you.